# Getting undesired space between 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why I'm getting the undesired space, I want the `clubs` and `events` divs to be in the same height but under the `header` div.

practically, I get a big space between the header and the clubs & events divs.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Metzo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="metzo">

        <div class="header">
        </div>
<!-- Getting a huge space here in the y-axis -->
        <div class="clubs">
        hello
        </div>
        <div id="space1"> </div>
        <div class="events">
        hello
            <?php 
                //include("event.php");
                //include("event.php");
                //include("event.php");
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the css:

```
html {background-color:black;}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin-top: 1%; color:white;}

.metzo 
    {
    width:80%;
    height: 80%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    /*margin-bottom:5%;*/
    text-align:center;
    }

.header
    {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    border:solid thick white;
    }

.clubs
    {
    display:inline-block;
    width:45%;
    height:100%;
    border:solid thick white;
    margin-top:0px;
    }

#space1 {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:3%;
    height:100%;
    float:top;
    /*border:solid thick white;*/
    }

.events
    {
    display:inline-block;
    width:45%;
    height:100%;
    border:solid thick white;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: That's because `#space1` element has `height: 100%` CSS declaration. means `100%` of its parent's height.

Comment: Actually, it's because the combined width of `.clubs`, `#space1`, and `.events` exceeds 100% of the parent, thus wrapping because of the `inline-block` property. Check my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UC7GE/

What on earth is `#space1` for? My solution uses `box-sizing` on the elements to enable specification of fluid width as well as fixed border width:

```
.clubs,
.events {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 46.5%;
    margin: 0
}
.events {
    margin-left: 3%; // instead of #space1
}
```

**EDIT:** I realize `#space1` is meant to be a space between `.clubs` and `.events`, but it's bad practice to use an empty element simply as a spacer. This solution gets along fine without it!

Comment: +1 for mentioning best practices, but you should probably mention that `box-sizing` isn't supported in IE7 or below, if anyone still cares about IE7 (I have to :()

Comment: Unreasonable constraints on answers, such as IE7 support, should really be clearly mentioned by the question's author. :)

Comment: That's a good point actually. I was only recommending it and not trying to demote your answer in any way :)

Comment: Any way, I *do* feel sorry for you for having to deal with that old browser.

Comment: [93.71%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) browser support. poor the remain 6.29%.

Comment: You say tomato, I say [inline-block itself has only 94.26% support](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block). So if that road has already been taken, then `border-box` doesn't make any significant difference.

Comment: Hah! Well than that's that problem solved. If nobody supported/used IE7 any more, we'd all be ok with IE8 and above I think

Answer (score 2):

Use height auto for .metzo class

```
.metzo {
        width:80%;
        height: auto;
        padding:0px;
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-right:10%;
        /*margin-bottom:5%;*/
        text-align:center;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#space1 {
display:inline-block; 
width:3%;
height:10%; /*Change the height*/
float:top;
}
```

You are defining the height with respect to the parent element which in this case is `metzo`

Answer (score 2):

Change in the CSS metzo Height:Auto;

```
.metzo {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.metzo height couses the gap

```
.metzo 
    {
    width:80%;
    /*height: 80%;*/
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    /*margin-bottom:5%;*/
    text-align:center;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LNwYq/